# Saving setting to buffer

Tags: gvim, buffers, default-settings

Is there a way to save the value of a setting to a buffer or a file?  For example, when I type

```
:set guifont
```

It displays the setting I want to use but as soon as I start typing in the buffer it disappears.  I'm trying to do this using gvim on Windows but I suspect the answer will be generic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are too(?) many ways to do this.

1) :mkexrc

```
:mkexrc [file]
```

writes all mappings and changed options to a file (.exrc by default)

2) Option window

```
:options
```

opens a buffer with extra UI to change options (the code is in $VIMRUNTIME/optwin.vim); of course, the buffer is accessible by standard Vim commands too

3) Expression register

```
i<C-R>=&guifont<CR>
```

will insert the value of option `guifont` into the current buffer

4) execute()

```
nnoremap <silent><leader>x :-1put=trim(execute(input(\":\")))<CR>
```

press `<leader>x` and then input any Vim command (e.g. `set`); the output will be inserted into the current buffer

Anything else I forgot?

Comment: Wow.  Very comprehensive.

Comment: 3) can be put `"=&guifont<CR>p` or `:put =&guifont`